# Error when trying to write two div elements The template root requires exactly one element.eslint-plugin-vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js

```html
<template>
  <div class="footerpart-container">
    <div class="general-container">
     dadada
    </div>

    <div class="legal-container">
     dadad
    </div>

    <div class="helpsupport-container">
     dadada
    </div>
      
  </div>

<div class="footer-two">
  <div class="follow-us">follow us</div>
 </div>
  
</template>
```

Under one template i have two div tags, Where i am trying to display first div on the top and second footer-two tag in the bottom.

After placing there i am getting error as

The template root requires exactly one element.eslint-plugin-vue

Comment: After? Horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Right now they are one after another. If you mean side by side then you already seem to have the answer. Just wrap your divs in another div and give it `display: flex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flexbox`.

When you use `display: flex` it align `flex-items` side-by-side because of its default `flex-position: row`. But to make `footerpart-container` and `footerparttwo-container` flex items you need to wrap both HTML element into a container(`footer-parent-container`)

```css
.footer-parent-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.footerpart-container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.footerparttwo-container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-parent-container">
  <div class="footerpart-container">
    <div class="general-container">
      sas
    </div>

    <div class="legal-container">
      <div class="legal-title">Legal</div>

    </div>

    <div class="helpsupport-container">
      <div class="helpsupport-title">Help & support</div>

    </div>
    <div class="whatsup-icon-helpnum">

      <div class="ph-num">180034014</div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="footerparttwo-container">
    <div class="follow-us">follow us</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Error when trying to write two div elements The template root requires exactly one element.eslint-plugin-vue

Comment: you just need to wrap these 2 `div` inside a single `div`